# Unique values in Report Builder Parameters without rerunning new query

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Report Builder 3 which runs a stored procedure and displays a simple table.  Next, we would like to filter based on the first column of data.  The first column of data might have 20 rows, and 3 possible values.

How can I make Report Builder display those 3 values in the parameter dropdown, *without* rerunning a SP or Query from the server?

(Running the SP that obtains the data takes several seconds, and it is not reasonable to rerun another query in order to populate the parameter dropdown)

**What I've tried:**

1) I create a parameter dropdown and select the column name as values for the dropdown.  Instead of getting 3 unique values, 20 rows appears in the parameter dropdown, with duplicates corresponding to the original dataset results.  How can I make them unqique?

2) Grouping by the values in the first column.  Grouping works, but we would still like to display a parameter dropdown that contains unique values from column one.

Comment: you could in your stored proc use a table to store results of the stored proc then use that table for the drop down, which should be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. (pretty cumbersome but maybe there's no choice) It seems extremely stubborn on the part of RB3 that they don't automatically make the parameter options unique.

Comment: Actually I just found the solution to create a 2nd parameter and reference the first parameter using a custom function like GetDistinctValues in the Report Code section.  If nobody else posts the solution I will do that tomorrow.